# build a model within a function returns "variable lengths differ (found for 'var')"

Tags: r

I am trying to build a function to run a model based on a list of variables.
The code works fine outside a function

```
data <- ovarian
model <- glm(fustat ~ rx, family = binomial(), data = data)
odds.ratio(model)
```

but when I try to do this in a function it returns an error

```
OR <- function(var){
  model <- glm(fustat ~ var, family = binomial(), data = data)
  return(odds.ratio(model))
}
OR("rx")

 Error in model.frame.default(formula = fustat ~ var, data = data, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'var')
```

Any idea how to get around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing string as input to the function, convert it into formula or something which can be coerced to a formula. One way would be to use `reformulate`.

```
OR <- function(var){
  model <- glm(reformulate(var, "fustat"), family = binomial(), data = data)
  return(odds.ratio(model))
}

OR("rx")
```